# Fastest way to append a string at the end of last line

Tags: awk, sed, echo

I need help regarding the fastest way one can append a string at the end of the last line in a file in bash (in-place).

Say, the input is

```
cat file.txt
first
second
```

I want to append the character `;` at the end of the last line. The expected output is

```
cat file.txt
first
second;
```

There is some solution using gnu `sed`, `echo`...

```
sed -i "$ s/$/;/" file.txt 
real    0m0.009s
echo "$(cat $i);" file.txt > temp.txt
real    0m0.007s
```

But again for the `echo`,  I need to move back the `temp.txt` to the original file which costs extra time. Moreover, I am not sure about this timing when the `file.txt` is a huge file of the order of a few gigabytes.

**What would be the most efficient way to append a string at the end of the last line?**

EDIT:

As @Ed Morton suggested, it is important to have a new line at the end of the file. In my example, although this is not the case.
But assuming that as well, in my case the character `;` needs to be at the last line which is not empty, i.e. on the same line as the word `second`.

Comment: Can we assume that the file is guaranteed to have a trailing newline?

Comment: @KamilCuk, there is no new line and the string has to be appended at the end of the last character of the last line. I find `echo ";" >> input.txt`  is much faster but it appends in a new line which is not wanted.

Comment: `printf ";" >> file` differs from "add semicolon __on the end of last line__". Is there a newline character _at the end of last line_?

Comment: No. Probably I did not express it correctly. There is no newline at the end of the file. The last line contains some strings. I want to append to that string but not creating new line.

Comment: @Boogeyman a file that doesn't end in a newline is not a valid POSIX text file and so YMMV with what any text-processing tool does with it. If that is the case you should mention that in your question as it's very important. You should probably also fix whatever is generating that file so that it does generate a valid POSIX text file!

Comment: Ahhh okay. I did not know that.

Answer (score 4):

To be clear - there is no real "in-place" editing in sed, perl, ruby, awk, python, etc. they all create a temp file behind the scenes and overwrite the original file with the output. `ed` doesn't use a temp file but it does read the whole input file into a buffer in memory (which you can do with those other tools too) which may not fit for a large file and wouldn't necessarily be any more efficient than creating a temp file.

If your input file does not already end in a newline, i.e. it's not a valid POSIX text file:

```
$ printf 'first\nsecond' > file.txt
$ cat -Ev file.txt
first$
second$
```

and you want it to remain like that after appending `;` then all you need is:

```
$ printf ';' >> file.txt
$ cat -Ev file.txt
first$
second;$
```

Change `printf ';'` to `printf ';\n'` if you want the output to be a valid POSIX text file.

If it does end in a newline and you want it to continue to end in a newline after appending `;` then to avoid temp files and buffers try this using GNU `truncate`

```
$ truncate -s -1 file.txt
$ printf ';\n' >> file.txt

$ cat -Ev file.txt
first$
second;$
```

If you don't have `truncate` you can do the same with the POSIX tools `wc` and `dd`:

```
$ length=$(wc -c < file.txt)
$ dd if=/dev/null of=file.txt obs="$((length-1))" seek=1
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000159 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `;` *on the end of the file* (which is not on the end of last line, when there is a trailing newline in the file) you could do:

```
printf ";" >> file
```

> **the fastest way**
>
> **the most efficient**

Prepare a C program:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);
   assert(fd > 0);
   lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_END);
   write(fd, ";\n", 2);
}
```

compile:

```
cc file.c -o add_trailing_semicolon
```

and then:

```
./add_trailing_semicolon file.txt
```